# Как сделать скролл на js при заходе на страницу

Tags: javascript, jquery

Я верстаю сайт и хочу сделать кое-что красивое. Мне нужно чтобы страница при заходе сразу скроллила до нужного элемента, но не знаю как это реализовать.

Answer (score 2):

Метод через вычисление позиции элемента, и прокрутки к этой позиции:

```js
document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{ // Ожидание готовности документа
    
    let div = document.querySelector('.my-div');

    window.scrollTo({
        top: div.offsetTop, // Здесь вычисление позиции может быть сложнее
        behavior: 'smooth', // Плавность прокрутки, убрать если не нужно
    });
    
});
```

```css
.my-div {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>123</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div>123</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div>123</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div class="my-div">123</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div>123</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div>123</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div>123</div>
```

Улучшенный метод, предложенный @Deonis (c) в комментарии:

```js
document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{ // Ожидание готовности документа
    
    document.querySelector('.my-div').scrollIntoView({
        behavior: 'smooth',
        block: 'start'
    });
    
});
```

```css
.my-div {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>123</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div>123</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div>123</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div class="my-div">123</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div>123</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div>123</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div>123</div>
```

У этого метода есть нюанс - он скролит все скролы - страницы и скроло-имеющих-родителей, чтобы элемент был в итоге в области видимости. Для "блока на странице" это отлично. А для "блоков в скрольных родителях" может не подойти из-за не всегда уместных движений страницы, как здесь в снипете "выполнить код".

Comment: [Можно без вычислений](https://jsfiddle.net/8693jaus/), используя метод `scrollIntoView`

Comment: @Deonis спасибо, не знал.